# Adding row and column names to graph in R

Tags: r, igraph, graph-theory

After creating a random graph in R, how do I add row names and column names to this graph.

Example, I have a graph:

```
 1 2 3 4
1 0 0 0 0
2 1 1 1 0
3 0 1 0 1
4 1 0 1 0
```

I want to label 1,2, 3 and 4 as A, B, C and D

I can convert the graph to matrix and I can add the row and column names. But can I add the row and column names directly in the graph?

Thanks

Priya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that you have a graph,  but then show an adjacency matrix, so it is not really clear where you are starting. I will cover two possibilities.

## 1. You have the graph and used it to write out the adjacency matrix.

In this case, set the node names by assigning the vertices a `label` attribute

```
library(igraph)
AM = matrix(c(0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0), ncol=4)

G1 = graph_from_adjacency_matrix(AM)

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(G1, vertex.size=20, main="Original")

## This will change the node names
V(G1)$label = LETTERS[1:4]
plot(G1, vertex.size=20, main="With Labels")
```

[image: Altered graph]

## 2. You just have the adjacency matrix and have not yet made the graph

In this case,  I might rather put the node names in first.

```
AM = matrix(c(0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0), ncol=4)
colnames(AM) = LETTERS[1:4]
rownames(AM) = LETTERS[1:4]

G2 = graph_from_adjacency_matrix(AM)
plot(G2, vertex.size=20)
```

[image: Graph 2]